# Execute python script from a php page

Tags: javascript, php, python, html

I'm trying to execute my javascript functions, that have PHP code inside, when I click on a button but once I load the page on browser all javascript functions execute without clicking any button. When I try to press a button and execute a function nothing happens.
My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title> LED </title>
    <script>
        function exec_vermelho(){
            <?php exec( "sudo python led.py 100 0 0" ); ?>
        }
        function exec_verde(){
            <?php exec( "sudo python led.py 0 100 0" ); ?>
        }
        function exec_azul(){
            <?php exec( "sudo python led.py 0 0 100" ); ?>
        }
        function exec_amarelo(){
            <?php exec( "sudo python led.py 100 100 0" ); ?>
        }
        function exec_ciano(){
            <?php exec( "sudo python led.py 0 100 100" ); ?>
        }
        function exec_magenta(){
            <?php exec( "sudo python led.py 100 0 100" ); ?>
        }
        function exec_branco(){
            <?php exec( "sudo python led.py 100 100 100" ); ?>
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" name="botao_vermelho" value="Vermelho" onclick="exec_vermelho()">
    <input type="button" name="botao_verde" value="Verde" onclick="exec_verde()">
    <input type="button" name="botao_azul" value="Azul" onclick="exec_azul()">
    <input type="button" name="botao_amarelo" value="Amarelo" onclick="exec_amarelo()">
    <input type="button" name="botao_ciano" value="Ciano" onclick="exec_ciano()">
    <input type="button" name="botao_magenta" value="Magenta" onclick="exec_magenta()">
    <input type="button" name="botao_branco" value="Branco" onclick="exec_branco()">
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why all PHP on functions execute once I load the page and then nothing happens when I click on a button? Do I need to change anything on the buttons or javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: WHY would you give Apache `sudo` access… _**WHY?**_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is server side code and will have executed all the code at the point you have loaded the page. Take a look at your source code in the browser and you will see that there is no javascript code inside your functions - You might want to look into using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score -1):

You can't make it like this, because PHP interprets your code before javascript. So it doesn't make sense to call a PHP function by Javascript.

You need to make an AJAX call to a php script, which runs the python script asynchronously.

Like:

```
// HTML
<input type="button" name="botao_vermelho" value="Vermelho">

// JS
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
         url: '/phpscript.php?button=' + $(this).attr('name'),
     }).done(function(data){
         console.log(data);
     });
});
```

And now just make a php script which runs your python executions. To know which button was clicked, i suppose the best way is to give the `name` attribute from each button to the php script.

Comment: He doesn't use jQuery...

Comment: Boah, then he may use plain javascript. I just didn't want to write that much code for an example.

Comment: then write an example using fetch api that is much easier then xhr :)

Comment: Why don't you write an example? Thanks for downvoting, btw.

Comment: Wasn't directly meant to you. It's just hilarious how a working example and a solution for the questioners problem is downvoted just like that.